# Adding New Div In Editable Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following JsFiddle for `editing a Div`, now I some how want too add a `div` which in edit mode `by default`.

When i click on `Add New div`,new div is added and then it can be edited by clicking `Edit` .
But i was wondering is there a way when i click on ADD New Div the div should be by default in Edit mode. Is there any way i can achieve it.

Following is [Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/UZkJ3/5/)

Thanks For Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as follows:

```
 $("#add").click(function () {
     $('#accordion').prepend($("#appendpanel").clone().removeAttr('id').find('.panel-title, .panel-collapse').attr('contenteditable',true).css('border','2px solid'));
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UZkJ3/9/)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UZkJ3/18/) as per comments

Note:
*There are other neat ways for doing what you want.
You can simply keep a hidden editable div, add its clone and make it visible..
Or create a function that dynamically adds the mark up you need..*

Side notes: *Please avoid using inline-css, here is why: [Why Use CSS @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Why_use_CSS)*

*for changing style attributes jQuery has a dedicated`css()` function*

*You don't need two `$(document).ready()` functions*

Comment: @RS26 i'm still working on it. have to say that your html is horrible... and please avoid using inline styles...

Comment: Ok waiting. I am new to developing so learning things. Will keep in mind your advice :)

Comment: @RS26 http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/UZkJ3/11/ there you have all the buttons, since you don't want the edit button anymore, simply remove it from your html..

Comment: I do need edit button, because if i click on done I should be able to Edit it again

Comment: Thanks. One more help if possible. How can i display message "No div" and then if div is added then the msg should hide. If again there is no div then the message should appear. :)

Comment: Thanks. Hope you got my ques? Suppose there are no subdiv in div than display msg "No div" and if Add new is clicked hide that msg :)

Comment: Sir you are just true class. Thanks, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hii, can u check this updated fiddle and help in showing the msg of Currently No div . Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/UZkJ3/19/

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but does the job ;)

```
$("#add").click(function () {

   var clone = $("#appendpanel").clone().removeAttr('id');
   $('#accordion').prepend(clone);

   // trigger a click event on the button, which makes the required div's content-editable
   clone.find("#edit1").trigger("click"); 
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/UZkJ3/6/)**

Updated:

Use this code in `$('#accordion').on('click', '.delete-link', function () {`

```
var children = $(".panel");
// get those not hidden
children = children.filter(
    function(index){
        return children.eq(index).css("display") !== "none"; 
    }
).length;

if(children === 1){  // the only child left is "Add new div"
     $("#message").show(500);
}
```

And this in `$("#add").click(function () {`

```
$("#message").hide(500);
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/UZkJ3/15/)**

Comment: Just one More help, any idea how can i show a message "No div present" if there are no div, and hide that message if new div is added

Comment: I'd say that this is some sort of hack. OP wanted to append the link in editable mode,  this solution is simply triggering the edit button manually..

Comment: @RS26 First, I am sorry for late response. The electricity power supply had cut off suddenly, now it's back, and this is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/UZkJ3/13/), adding explanation.